# JQuery post not running code in PHP file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, cookies

I have a PHP file called `temp.php` which has the following code:

```
$expiry = 86400;
if (isset($_POST['action'])) {
switch ($_POST['action']) {
    case 'add':

    if (!isset($_COOKIE['ids'])) {

        $value = $_GET['id'];
        $ids = array($value);
        setcookie('ids', serialize($ids), $expiry);

    } else {

        $value = $_GET['id'];
        $ids = unserialize($_COOKIE['ids']);
        if (!in_array($value, $ids)) {

            array_push($ids, $value);
        } 
        setcookie('ids', serialize($ids), $expiry);
    }
    break;
}
```

I run this code using `$.POST('temp.php', {'action': 'add'}, function(data))`.

Basically on a button click I execute the post function and want to add the id in the URL parameter to the existing array in the cookie otherwise create an array. However I can see any cookies being created. Not even if the only code I have is setcookie(...)

Comment: But if you send the request as POST then `$_GET` will be empty...

Comment: even if the only code i have in my file is                                          setcookie($name, $value, $expiry), no cookie is added @Technoh

Comment: You need to send an id to the server on your ajax call:    `$.POST('temp.php?id=.....', {'action': 'add'}, function(data))`

Comment: Try adding an `error_log` call just after `isset($_POST['action'])` to see if the PHP file is loaded properly. If you don't get anything from your `error_log` call then your error is elsewhere.

Comment: You have a open curly bracket, need one after `break;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting your cookie to expire: Fri, 02 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT.

Eliminate using your variable `$expiry` or change it to a timestamp, `setcookie()` wants a Unix timestamp for the integer, not the amount of time. [PHP: setcookie() man page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php)

```
setcookie('ids', serialize($ids), time() + 86400)  // 1 Day;
```

And fix your missing curly bracket after `break;`